# How to position nodes sequentially nz-graph?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

How to make node `a` be placed at the level of its neighbor node `b`?

[image]

```
{
  nodes: [
    {id: `enter`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `a`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `b`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `c`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `exit`, width: 100, height: 100},
  ],
  edges: [
    {v: `enter`, w: `a`},
    {v: `a`, w: `c`},
    {v: `c`, w: `exit`},
    {v: `enter`, w: `b`},
    {v: `b`, w: `exit`},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  nodes: [
    {id: `enter`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `a`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `b`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `c`, width: 100, height: 100},
    {id: `exit`, width: 100, height: 100},
  ],
  edges: [
    {v: `enter`, w: `a`},
    {v: `a`, w: `c`},
    {v: `c`, w: `exit`},
    {v: `enter`, w: `c`},
    {v: `b`, w: `exit`},
  ]
}
```

Comment: I see that you've changed one of the edges, but this answer is somewhat unclear without any further explanation.  Please consider an [edit] to clarify the answer.